# Problem with custom loop and wp_list_pluck

Tags: php, categories, loop

I'm trying to create a multi column layout in the category archive. Thanks to the community I was able to find all the answers except this one... I'm sure it's easy-peasy for someone more advanced :)

1. Here's the part that works just fine:

   I wanted to create this type of layout:

[image: Layout 01]

So the first four posts from the same category are wrapped in one div, and the 5th post in another div (posts 1-4 are excluded)...the code used for this works as expected:

```
 <div class="cell medium-6 large-3 decor-list">          
        <?php 
        $first_grid_query = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'posts_per_page'=>4,
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
            ));
        while ($first_grid_query->have_posts()) : $first_grid_query->the_post(); ?>                       
        <div class="some-content-here">
          //bla bla bla
        </div>
        <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>
<div class="cell large-6 main-cont">
    <?php 
    $first_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $first_grid_query->posts, 'ID' ); 
    $second_grid_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page'=>1,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
            // Add the post ids from the first loop
            'post__not_in' => $first_grid_posts_ids,
        )
    );
    while ($second_grid_query->have_posts()) : $second_grid_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="some-content-here">
          //bla bla bla
        </div>
    <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>                           
   <div class="cell medium-6 large-3 quote-container">
        <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('archive-cat-widget')) : else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
```

**2. But when I'm trying to add another container with posts 6-13 (and exclude posts 1-5), the code doesn't work - the loop starts from the post number 1 so the posts are duplicated...**

[image: Layouy02]

and here's the code:

```
                    <?php 
                    $first_grid_query = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'posts_per_page'=>4,
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
                        ));
                    while ($first_grid_query->have_posts()) : $first_grid_query->the_post(); ?>                       
                    <div class="some-content-here">
                     //bla bla bla
                    </div>
                    <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </div>

            <div class="cell large-6 main-cont">
                <?php 
                $first_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $first_grid_query->posts, 'ID' ); 
                $second_grid_query = new WP_Query(
                    array(
                        'posts_per_page'=>1,
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
                        // Add the post ids from the first loop
                        'post__not_in' => $first_grid_posts_ids,
                    )
                );
                while ($second_grid_query->have_posts()) : $second_grid_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="some-content-here">
                     //bla bla bla
                    </div>
                <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>                           
                <div class="cell medium-6 large-3 quote-container">
                    <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('archive-cat-widget')) : else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                    <div class="cell large-6 main-cont">
                <?php 
                    $first_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $first_grid_query->posts, 'ID' );
                    $second_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $second_grid_query->posts, 'ID' ); 
                    $third_grid_query = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'posts_per_page'=>8,
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
                            // Add the post ids from the first and second loop
                            'post__not_in' => array(
                                    $first_grid_posts_ids,
                                    $second_grid_posts_ids,
                                )
                        )
                    );
                    while ($third_grid_query->have_posts()) : $third_grid_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="some-content-here">
                     //bla bla bla
                    </div>
                    <?php  endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                </div>
```

I think the problem is somewhere here:

```
$first_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $first_grid_query->posts, 'ID' );
$second_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $second_grid_query->posts, 'ID' ); 
                $third_grid_query = new WP_Query(
                    array(
                        'posts_per_page'=>8,
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
                        // Add the post ids from the first and second loop
                        'post__not_in' => array(
                                $first_grid_posts_ids,
                                $second_grid_posts_ids,
                            )
                    )
                );
```

When I exclude only `$first_grid_posts_ids` or `$second_grid_posts_ids` like so:
`post__not_in' => $first_grid_posts_ids,` or `post__not_in' => $second_grid_posts_ids,`
the posts from the first or second loop are excluded, but when I add those ids in an array, the code doesn't work.

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Comment: have you tried and use `array_merge( )` to merge the two ids arrays?

Comment: Please don't add SOLVED to the title. You can post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

You need to change this part of code before 3rd query... it will merge you previous queries and exclude posts from them:

```
$first_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $first_grid_query->posts, 'ID' ); 
$second_grid_posts_ids = wp_list_pluck( $second_grid_query->posts, 'ID' ); 
$allTheIDs = array_merge( $first_grid_posts_ids , $second_grid_posts_ids );
$third_grid_query = new WP_Query(
                        array(
                            'posts_per_page'=>4,
                            'post_type' => 'post',
                            'cat' => get_query_var('cat'),
                            // Add the post ids from the first and second loop
                            'post__not_in' => $allTheIDs
                        )
                    );
```